# proper prefix to force MongoDB to interpret a string as unicode?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to store unicode information in a MongoDB database so that I can render characters on a web page.  I understand that MongoDB stores everything in BSON format and, in particular, stores BSON strings with utf-8 encoding (as per [this link](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#a-note-on-unicode-strings)), so I bet this question can be resolved by someone who knows more than I do.

The problem: I want to render Hebrew characters.  I made a CSV file in which I list their unicode code points as plain text and I need to figure out what prefix to include in this text string so that I can properly handle it with MongoDB.

A string such as "05D8" has no problem -- in my CSV file, it is represented as "05D8" and then in MongoDB that comes through as "05D8" no problem.

However, the string "05E0" -- meaning, U+05E0 in unicode -- the Hebrew letter "nun" -- is being ingested by MongoDB and coerced into an integer... scientific notation interpretation.  Ten characters in the Hebrew alphabet all have this issue even though MongoDB is ingesting all of my other strings properly.

Two questions:
Q1: What prefix should I put on the front of the strings in the CSV file in order to get MongoDB to treat "05E0" as U+05E0?  u'.. u"...   I've tried u'05E0' but that gets stored in MongoDB as "u'05E0'" which is not quite what I want. (that's my problem, not mongo's problem -- I just can't figure out what to type in the CSV file)

Q2: is there a flag for `mongoimport` with which I can force the information from this CSV to be interpreted as text and not as scientific notation?

Comment: Okay, this seems to work:

Comment: `eval("'\\u" + "05E0" + "'")`

Comment: Not familiar with MongoDB, but have you tried just writing UTF-8 strings to the .CSV?